# how to add current date time in bigint field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I need to add the current date time in a bigint field in a database... and then display from that only the date in format: october 1, 2009.

I am currently thinking of storing the value in string variable and then converting it to int...
String s = DateTime.Now.ToString();

i dont know what to do next..
please help

Answer (score 4):

You could just store the number of ticks as your bigint value.  Ticks represent the number of elapsed 1/10,000 of milliseconds since January 1, 0001.

```
DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

This can always be converted back to a DateTime by using the constructor that accepts a long:

```
DateTime storedTime = new DateTime(ticksFromDatabase);
```

To format your date, just use any of the standard [date format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).  A custom format string might work better actually, I just perused them and it doesn't look like there's a built in one for the format you want.  This should work:

```
date1.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
```

Comment: i stored it as

long s= DateTime.Now.Ticks;

but i am using a SQL datasource to display it in  a gridview.

What should i write in the select query...???

My SQL query is..
"SELECT MachineGroups.MachineGroupID, MachineGroups.MachineGroupName, MachineGroups.MachineGroupDesc, MachineGroups.TimeAdded, MachineGroups.CanBeDeleted, COUNT(Machines.MachineName) AS 'No. of PCs' FROM MachineGroups FULL OUTER JOIN Machines ON Machines.MachineGroupID = MachineGroups.MachineGroupID GROUP BY MachineGroups.MachineGroupID, MachineGroups.MachineGroupName, MachineGroups.MachineGroupDesc, MachineGroups.TimeAdded

Comment: You'll need to hook into the RowDataBound event and reformat the date.  Is there any reason you can't use a sql DateTime column?  That would be the easiest thing to do, since you could format it both with SQL select statements and easily transfer it to DateTime objects in c#.

Comment: no i cant use datetime coz the entire company code is in bigint..:(

I kno it would have been so easy for me too..

But i seriously did not get how to display the date in a gridview using the select statement...

Please help me man...

Comment: i m not able to figure out how to use datebound


what o do with this


DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = dt1.Date.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a smart date key, since it's easier to find that using SQL:

```
20090927235000
yyyyMMddhhmmss
```

This way, if you want to find anything that happened on a given day, you could do:

```
select * from tbl where datecol between 20090927000000 and 20090927240000
```

Thereby making data validation *a lot* easier, even if you are using an ORM.